# NodePort resource - is it one ip for all nodeports in the cluster and only the port changes?

Tags: kubernetes

How does a NodePort get it's IP address? and if I create 100 nodePorts in my cluster, do I have 100 different ips or it's the same ip address and only the ports change ? who decide about the ip the nodePort is given ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport):

> Kubernetes control plane allocates a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range flag (default: 30000-32767). Each node proxies that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service.

So in short, k8s will open port on each node and connections to this port are then forwarded to the service’s cluster IP. So 100 nodeports will have 100 different ClusterIPs and ports.

Comment: I talked about the IP address not about the port

Comment: Read it again carefully please. I said `100 different ClusterIPs and ports` - witch means that every service that has will have unique IP within cluster and unique ports, so for 100 services you will have `100 different INTERNAL IP's` and 100 different ports.

Comment: A NodePort has a cluster-unique TCP port, and every node in the cluster listens on that port.  If you have 100x NodePort Services and 20 Nodes then you'll have 2,000 reachable host:port pairs.

Comment: but NodePort can be reached from outside of the cluster -  so from where will I get so many ports? isn't limited resource? why did you write "internal IPS"?  it'a a nodePort not clusterIp

Comment: Each service has internal IP anyway (nodeport is build on top of clusterip). K8s opens port on every host and routes it to this internal service ip, so it does not matter to which host you connect. Please read this article, it should help you understand it better: https://www.tkng.io/services/nodeport/.
Ports number is limited.